# How to traverse nested document recursively in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to traverse recursively to the nth node in a MongoDB model. Here is my user Model.

**User Model**

```
var UserSchema  = new Schema({
    firstname : { type: String},
    parents:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    children:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    partner:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    sibling:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

I don't know how to generate a tree like structure from this model, any  ideas on how to implement this ?, I'm using Mongoose for the model and also tried deep tree and populate didn't worked out as it works only for the first level.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you have an example of your populated document?

Comment: The major problem with trying to perform more that one level of population, in this case, is when a user has a `parents` value referencing another user and that user has a `children` value referencing the first user. If you try to auto-populate it recursively you'll create an infinite loop. If you were to start with a child and work your way up the tree to show all the parents, then you should be safe, but you'd still need to keep track of all of the userIds to make sure you didn't accidentally make a user their own ancestor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this is to use bluebird promises, specifically the `each`, `props`, `reduce` and `map` methods, depending on your use case.

In your case, I'd suggest something along the lines of

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User');

function getUser(userId) {
  return UserModel.findOne({_id: userId}).lean().exec()
    .then(function(user){
      return bluebird.props({
        firstName: user.firstName,
        parents: bluebird.map(user.parents, getUser),
        children: bluebird.map(user.children, getUser),
        partner: bluebird.map(user.partner, getUser),
        sibling: bluebird.map(user.sibling, getUser)
      })
    });
}

// Then call getUser once on the root node, e.g.
getUser(rootUserObjectId)
  .then(function(userTree){
    console.log(userTree)
  })
```

Let me know how that goes!